# i want to fetch this informatino php array?

Tags: php, arrays

in that array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [programs] => Google Maps
            [version] => 3.4.5
            [type] => Internet 
            [description] => dasdsdasd
            [views] => 7
            [serial] => xx-yy-zz-iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
        )

)
```

i want to fetch that information

```
[id] => 2
[programs] => Google Maps
[version] => 3.4.5
[type] => Internet 
[description] => dasdsdasd
[views] => 7
[serial] => xx-yy-zz-iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

**NEW:**
try it but it's the result of a search in db , it can be more than one record and i want to fetch the program name from each record...the problem is that each record store in the array as stdclass object so how can i deal with that

Comment: Have you tried `$array[0]`? If yes, what'd you get?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve ?

Comment: i want to achieve the name of the program for example Google MAps

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read up on the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php). It is probably one of the best written documentations out there.
That being said, let's try and help you.

To get access to the stdClass Object you need to use, the proper index, in that example [0], meaning:

```
$array[0]
```

To gain access to the properties of the object, you need to use ->, meaning:

```
$array[0]->id
```

Remember, you can always save a reference, like so:

```
$foo=$array[0];
```

And, be careful that properties of the object are literal strings, you might be inclined to use $, but don't!

Comment: This is done, assuming your array is named $array. If the variable has a different name, substitute as needed.

Comment: What is the name of your variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_info = $topArray[0]
```

This is utterly basic barebones PHP (or most any programming language).

Comment: it give error : Can't convert stdClass object to string when i want to echo it

Comment: You can't echo a stdClass object. Try var_dump() or print_r. How'd you get this data anyways? json_decode, perhaps? There's a second parameter for that to return a regular array instead of a stdClass object

Comment: try it but it's the result of a search in db , it can be more than one record and i want to fetch the program name from each record...the problem is that each record store in the array as stdclass object so how can i deal with that

Answer (score 0):

if the array is called $my_array use this code:

```
$my_array[0]->id;
```

This will get you the id, change id to whatever variable you need.

This is how you access objects as the item in the array is an object.

To convert the object to an array use:

```
$array = (array) $obj;
```

Comment: yeah i tried it, it says error can't convert stdClass object to string